# Custom SonarQube rule - get List element type

Tags: java, sonarqube

While testing new rules I noticed that there is one bug. My rule is checking for method parameters and return type and is checking if those values owner has certain annotation.

Previously I had problem of getting Array in method parameters and getting element type of that Array. But then I found solution:

```
 if (parameterType.isArray()) {
                Type.ArrayType arrayType = (Type.ArrayType) parameterType;
                Type arrayElementType = arrayType.elementType();
...
```

But currently I have another issue. My rule found List as return value. I tried to find something similar to Type.ArrayType but with no success.

Is there a way to get List element type?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : no there is not. Parameterized types are not provided as part of the semantic API.

We already have in mind to provide this at some point : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1871

but no clear plan defined as of today.

Comment: Thank you for response.